# Simple hosting of a .NET Core Web API Service (Similar to NodeJs)

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Nuget Package that works on a .NET Core Web API Service when it is proxied by my API Management Server.  I would like to setup some automated testing of this service to be run when I run my builds.

Normally, when I want to run a service to be seen from other computers, I host it in IIS.  But I would rather not have to have IIS up and running on my build servers.

**I am wondering, is there a simple way to host a .Net Core Web API Service that can just run in-memory?** (Similar to the way NodeJs can be run)  I understand that Kestrel is used under the hood for ASP.NET Core.  Maybe it be setup to do that?

NOTE: Because this will be proxied by my API Management Server, it need to be accessible by other servers on my network.  (Not just localhost.)

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel is the simplest way you can use to achieve, you can config kestrel to enable it listening to remote request, see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration)